# Is my statement correct?

Tags: matrix-calculus

I was reading up on the inverse function theorem and I was wondering if the following thought I had was correct:

> If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are eachothers inverse functions and $f,g$ are both continuously differentiable, does that imply that the the derivatives $f'$ and $g'$ are invertible themselves? And more specifically is $f'$ the inverse of $g'$ and vice versa?

My first reaction would be yes since it follows that the Jacobian of the composite functions is simply the identity. Therefore the Jacobians of $f$ and $g$ are inverses. Is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: Try $n = 1$, $f = g = \mathsf{id}_{\Bbb{R}}$.

Comment: Perhaps it's badly worded, but if it asks what I think it asks, it is indeed true that *if* $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ *are continuously differentiable* at each point *and* $f\circ g=g\circ f=id_{\Bbb R^n}$, *then* $\nabla f(x)\cdot \nabla g(f(x))=\nabla g(f(x))\cdot \nabla f(x)=I_n$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^n$. It follows directly from the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule
$$
D (f \circ g) ({\bf x}) = Df(g({\bf x})) Dg({\bf x})
$$
and for the identity operator
$$
DI({\bf x}) = I
$$
Since $f \circ g = I$, what this tells you is that for any ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the matrix $Df(g({\bf x}))$ and $Dg({\bf x})$ are inverses of each other and, by symmetry, the same is true for $Dg(f({\bf x}))$ and $Df({\bf x})$.